# Memory allocation to structures in C++

Tags: c++

Are **different** data types in a **structure** also **stored sequentially** in computer's memory like arrays ?

Comment: [There may be padding between the members](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/1171191).

Comment: If I define two types of data for example an integer and a character inside a structure then will their addresses be just after one another....@MattiVirkkunen

Answer (score 0):

Structure and array follow same storing process. Difference is structure can hold different types of data but array don't.